# Is there a way to get just the ANSI characters from a string? Utf8decode fails when string contains emojis

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-7, emoji, ansi

First I get a TMemoryStream from an HTTP request, which contains the body of the response.
Then I load it in a TStringList and save the text in a widestring (also tried with ansistring).

The problem is that I need to convert the string because the users language is spanish, so vowels with accent marks are very common and I need to store the info.

```
lServerResponse := TStringList.Create;
lServerResponse.LoadFromStream(lResponseMemoryStream);

lStringResponse := lServerResponse.Text;
lDecodedResponse := Utf8Decode(lStringResponse );
```

If the response (a part of it) is "Hólá Múndó", lStringResponse value will be "HÃ³lÃ¡ MÃºndÃ³", and lDecodedResponse will be "Hólá Múndó".

But if the user adds any emoji (lStringResponse value will be "HÃ³lÃ¡ MÃºndÃ³ ðŸ˜€" if the emoji is ) Utf8Decode fails and returns an empty string.
Is there a way to get just the ANSI characters from a string (or MemoryStream)?, or removing whatever Utf8Decode can't convert?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TMemoryStream` is just raw bytes. There is no reason to loading that stream into a `TStringList` just to extract a `(Wide|Ansi)String` from it.  You can assign the bytes directly to an `AnsiString`/`UTF8String` using `SetString()` instead, eg:

```pascal
var
  lStringResponse: UTF8String;
  lDecodedResponse: WideString;
begin
  SetString(lStringResponse, PAnsiChar(lResponseMemoryStream.Memory), lResponseMemoryStream.Size);
  lDecodedResponse := UTF8Decode(lStringResponse);
end;
```

Just make sure the HTTP content really is encoded as UTF-8, or else this approach will not work.

That being said - `UTF8Decode()` (and `UTF8Encode()`) in Delphi 7 **DO NOT** support Unicode codepoints above U+FFFF, which means they **DO NOT** support Emojis at all.  That was fixed in Delphi 2009.

To work around that issue in earlier versions, you can use the Win32 API [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) function instead, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., Windows;

function My_UTF8Decode(const S: UTF8String): WideString;
var
  WLen: Integer;
begin
  WLen := MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, PAnsiChar(S), Length(S), nil, 0);
  if WLen > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, WLen);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, PAnsiChar(S), Length(S), PWideChar(Result), WLen);
  end else
    Result := '';
end;

var
  lStringResponse: UTF8String;
  lDecodedResponse: WideString;
begin
  SetString(lStringResponse, PAnsiChar(lResponseMemoryStream.Memory), lResponseMemoryStream.Size);
  lDecodedResponse := My_UTF8Decode(lStringResponse);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
uses
  ..., Windows;

function My_UTF8Decode(const S: PAnsiChar; const SLen: Integer): WideString;
var
  WLen: Integer;
begin
  WLen := MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, S, SLen, nil, 0);
  if WLen > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, WLen);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, S, SLen, PWideChar(Result), WLen);
  end else
    Result := '';
end;

var
  lDecodedResponse: WideString;
begin
  lDecodedResponse := My_UTF8Decode(PAnsiChar(lResponseMemoryStream.Memory), lResponseMemoryStream.Size);
end;
```

Or, use a 3rd party Unicode conversion library, like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) or [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/), which handle this for you.

Comment: [ICONV v1.16 pre-compiled DLLs can be downloaded here](https://github.com/pffang/libiconv-for-Windows/tree/master/lib64).

Comment: ... or use an actual Delphi version

Comment: I had already tried to solve the problem using MultiByteToWideChar without success, I'm glad I asked. Thank you.

Comment: Delphi Coder, Im just an employee, I can't make those decisions

Comment: @Daniel Maybe you can't make decisions on that, but you can demand the best tools for your job. See #9 on [Joel's checklist](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/).